# how does pulsar handle newly added brokers/bookies

Tags: apache-pulsar

I am investigating how pulsar treat the newly added nodes in detail but unable to find useful information under the public pulsar doc and google. the only thing I found is pulsar load balancing and it's mostly talking about how pulsar group topics into bundles, split a bundle with heavy load and load shedding for overloaded brokers(seems bookie is not the concern here). so I have some questions which needs more insights(and appreciate if you know any of them!)

For newly added broker nodes.

1. could it be idle/low usage for a long time? or pulsar has some mechanism to immediately unload some topics from existing brokers when it discovers the newly added brokers. say if the load is low in average and I am trying to add more brokers just for better latency. if topics can not be moved to the new brokers, then it's not feasible.
2. I am more concerned about thundering herd problems. it's nature to add more brokers when the cluster is overloaded. since the newly added brokers have very low usage, many topics could be assigned to the few newly added broker nodes(assume we only add few).

same questions applied for newly added bookies.
I am not sure if stackoverflow is the right place to ask those questions and please let me know if there is a better place to post them(creating issue under pulsar? but mine are more like questions).